# Natbib In-Text Citation displays (author?)

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I have taken a look through many other questions on this subject but cannot seem to fix my issue. Essentially while references display correctly I cannot get the author citation to appear in my text despite running pdflatex followed by bibtex followed by two more runs of pdflatex. Any help would be appreciated.

Sample tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Blahblahblah \citet*{Test12}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

refs.bib:

```
@article{Test12,
author = "John Smith",
title = "Test Article",
year = "2012",
journal = "The Test Journal"
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How can be duplicate to question which has been asked one year after this?

Comment: Because the new one is answered. I'm also voting to close.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use the bibstyle file:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

and it should word.

[image]

And if you really want a numbered bibliography use also

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

Answer (score 14):

As you surely get as output:

> " Package natbib warning: Author undefined for citation `Test12' "

The reason is because your `\bibliographystyle{plain}` uses numbers for references and not the author-year style.

In order for you to get the author name, you need a style that author-year compatible, such as IEEEtranSN, IEEEtranN or any other of your choice.

Please refer to the `natbib` [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) for more.