# Citing problem in Elsarticle

Tags: natbib, elsarticle

I'm trying to cite in parenthesis format with the name of the author and the year but when I compile it, it keeps asking for the name of the author. here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\citet{H}

\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{Biblio}

\end{document}
```

and here is my .bib file:

```
@article{AAA,
author = {AAAuthor},
title = {TTTitle},
year = {2017}
}
```

Comment: In your example, it should be `\citet{AAA}`, and you should run: `latex myfile.tex`, `bibtex myfile.aux`, `latex myfile.tex`, `latex myfile.tex` to get the reference list properly resolved.

Comment: From the [natbib documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) section 2.3, "The authors can only be listed if the .bst file supports author–year citations. The standard .bst files, such as plain.bst are numerical only and transfer no author–year information to LaTeX." But this is largely a duplicate of [Natbib In-Text Citation displays (author?)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111790/), and changing your bibliography style to an Author-Year format like `plainnat` resolves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `elsarticle-num-names`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{AAA,
  author = {A. Uthor},
  title = {TTTitle},
  year = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\citet{AAA}

\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents*` just to have a self-contained example, you can use the external file as usual.

[image]

Comment: It's working perfectly. Thanks. In case I want year included in my citation I have to cite year individually. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can use an option in `elsarticle` to get author-year style.