# Natbib, and the problem of custom bibliography styles

Tags: natbib

So, I tried asking this without much luck. Here is try 2.

My problem is that I am getting the same error as [this user](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111790/natbib-in-text-citation-displays-author).
The suggested (and effective) solution was to simply change the bibliography style to something like plainnat.

However, I don't want to use one of the built in natbib styles. The [style I want](http://library.williams.edu/citing/styles/acs.php) instead to use, is that of the Journal of the American Chemical Society, the style file for this is [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/chembst/JAmChemSoc.bst).

I want superscript numbers for in-text citation, and to follow the JAmCS format for the bibliography. I have pasted my preamble below

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}

\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{\bf \LARGE \thechapter}{0.3em}{\bf\LARGE}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
```

Where of course, the only relevant line (I think) should be the format of me calling the natbib package.

In my report, a citation looks like this for a citation in the text with explicit reference to the authors

```
\citet{Aviram1974} did some amazing work on blah blah blah
```

A normal citation (one not referred to in body text) looks like this

```
Molecular rectifiers were first suggested in 1974. \citep{Aviram1974}
```

At the end of my report, I have

```
\bibliographystyle{JAmChemSoc}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

With of course, the .bst from above in the same folder as the main file. With this code, I get the exact same error described in the linked post, namely that I have that weird [author?] warning in front of all of my intext citations, followed by a superscript corresponding to the citation. Of course, all I really want is the superscript by itself. I suspect that this has to do with citation style compatibility with the natbib options from the preamble but I don't know enough about either natbib nor citation style file structure to figure out how to fix it.

I'll throw in my minimal working example below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
    \usepackage[super]{natbib}

\begin{document}
Hello!\citep{Aviram1974}
\citet{Aviram1974} was a pretty cool research group.

\bibliographystyle{JAmChemSoc}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for trying to help out!

EDIT: Hi all, for anybody else that has this same problem, I have managed to find a solution and so thought to update my post accordingly. I just downloaded the achemso package from CTAN https://www.ctan.org/pkg/achemso?lang=en

Combined with natbib, it can be used as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
        \usepackage{achemso} %This line is important, note that I don't actually call natbib

    \begin{document}
    Hello!\citep{Aviram1974}
    \citet{Aviram1974} was a pretty cool research group.

   % note here that I don't actually use the \bibliographystyle{achemso} command, evidently just calling the package in the preamble is enough.
    \bibliography{Bibliography}

    \end{document}
```

This should produce the type of bibliography I was looking for.

Comment: Your question needs a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). However, you basically cannot use this bibliography style with these commands because the style determines what information is available and it does not, it seems, include the author. You could adapt the style so that it provides the information required, but then it would no longer be the standard journal style. If you are submitting this to the journal, this is likely to be no good and you will need to provide authors' names in the text yourself. If not, it will be easier to find another style.

Comment: So, looking at the [guidelines of the AmCS](http://library.williams.edu/citing/styles/acs.php) it says that what you want is superscripted numbers for in-text citations with the shown bibliography style. So, do you mean to say that the problem is with the .bst file that I listed? I thought it was strange that it was complaining about a missing author too.

Comment: No, the problem is that you cannot use e.g. `\citet` with this `.bst` style because the style doesn't provide that information for citation commands.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah I did research and figured that looking for an appropriate .bst file was a lost cause. I instead just downloaded the achemso package and it seems to have worked for me. Thanks for all your help, probably wouldn't have thought to look to the .bst with any confidence without you!

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer? That helps keep the site tidy and will enable other users with the same question to see you've found an answer.