# Is bibtex unable to \cite specific entry (author, title) in latex?

Tags: bibtex

I am working with bibliography. For this there are two way, one is using bibtex and another is biber. When I print bibliography using biber, then it give me desired result. Means it can print title, author etc at specific places in my document.  But bibtex is unable to do this. Using bibtex, my bibliography is generated, but when I use `\citeauthor{is4562000}` to print authorname, it shows "author?". Can we print authorname, title and year using bibtex. Here is code.

### `demo.bib`

```
@book{is4562000,
  title={Indian Standard Plain and reinforced concrete--code of
  practice (IS 456 : 2000)},
  shorttitle = {IS 456~:~2000},
  author={Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2},
  %author={Morrison, Norving,peter},
  journal={New Delhi: },
  year={2000},
  publisher={Bureau of Indian Standards},
}
```

### Main document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
%Includes "References" in the table of contents
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

%Title, date an author of the document
\title{Bibliography management: BibTeX}
\author{Manpreet}

%Begining of the document
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\medskip

\section{First Section}
This is bibliography using bibtex \cite{is4562000}\\

\citeauthor{is4562000}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{demo}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You're making two errors: the author is corporate so it must get an additional pair of braces; second, the bib style is not compatible with `natbib`, use `unsrtnat`.

Note the `author` field should be

```
author={{Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2}},
```

Here's a full example, where I used `filecontents*` just for avoiding clobbering my files.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{is4562000,
  title={Indian Standard Plain and reinforced concrete--code of practice (IS 456 : 2000)},
  shorttitle = {IS 456~:~2000},
  author={{Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2}},
  journal={New Delhi: },
  year={2000},
  publisher={Bureau of Indian Standards},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
%Includes "References" in the table of contents
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

%Title, date an author of the document
\title{Bibliography management: BibTeX}
\author{Manpreet}

%Begining of the document
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\medskip

\section{First Section}
This is bibliography using bibtex \cite{is4562000}

\citeauthor{is4562000}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `@book` entry type doesn't recognize a field called `journal`. I would therefore change the name of the field from `journal` to `address`, and omit `: ` after `New Delhi`.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from your bibliographic style, i.e. the `unsrt`.

Using the bibliographic style `plainnat`,

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{is4562000,
    author={{Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2}},
    title={Indian Standard Plain and reinforced concrete--code of practice (IS 456  2000)},
    shorttitle = {IS 456~:~2000},
    journal={New Delhi: },
    year={2000},
    publisher={Bureau of Indian Standards},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
This is bibliography using bibtex \cite{is4562000}.

\citeauthor{is4562000}.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

we get

[image]

which is not really nice, I agree.

With `biber`, you can have

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{is4562000,
    author={{Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2}},
    title={Indian Standard Plain and reinforced concrete--code of practice (IS 456  2000)},
    shorttitle = {IS 456~:~2000},
    journal={New Delhi: },
    year={2000},
    publisher={Bureau of Indian Standards},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}
\begin{document}
This is bibliography using biber~\cite{is4562000}.

\citeauthor{is4562000}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

A third option is to use `biblatex`, and I recommend this one (for personal taste). It supports `\citeauthor{key}` command:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{is4562000,
    author={{Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2}},
    title={Indian Standard Plain and reinforced concrete--code of practice (IS 456  2000)},
    shorttitle = {IS 456~:~2000},
    journal={New Delhi: },
    year={2000},
    publisher={Bureau of Indian Standards},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}
\begin{document}
This is bibliography using biblatex \cite{is4562000}.

\citetitle{is4562000}.

\citeauthor{is4562000}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Gives you:

[image]

Comment: I just realized that this post was probably a duplicate of [that one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111790/34551). Especially, [that answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111792/34551) could answer your question too.

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't it be `author={{Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2}}`?

Comment: You probably know that better than I do `!-)`. Since we're at it, couldn't it be equivalently `author={{C}ement and {C}oncrete {S}ectional {C}ommittee, {CED} 2},` ? Of course, feel free to edit my answer to improve it.

Comment: The salient issues for the "author" field of the entry at hand are twofold: (i) `and` should not be treated as a keyword that separates authors, and (ii) the comma should not be treated as the separator between the family name component and the first and von components. I.e., `CED 2` is *not* the first name and `Concrete Sectional Committee` is *not* the family name of somebody named `CED 2 Concrete Sectional Committee`. The way to get around these issues is to encase the entire author field in a second pair of curly braces, as @egreg has suggested.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who respond. By default it print bibliography in author year style. Sometime we don't want authoryear style, Then what to do?. And why \citeauthor{is4562000} not working in other styles ieeetr, plain etc?. These are problems comes with bibtex. when we use biblatex with biber to generate bibliography, then we don,t face such problems.

Comment: You should edit your question to make your point clear, I think. I don't exactly see you point. Mabybe @egreg does, but he probably was not notified that you posted that additional comment. And, one way to thank is to upvote answers. Ask if you don't know how to edit or how to upvote.

Comment: Is \citetitle {key} not supported by natbib?

Comment: @user93268 Edit your question or ask another question. Ask if you don't know how to do that. Biblatex supports the `\citetitle` command, see my edited answer.

Comment: After the edit, the first two screenshots seem to be out of sync with the associated code. Specifically, "CED 2" still comes before "Concrete Sectional Committee" in the formatted reference, and it's still missing from the citation call-outs.

Comment: Thank you, Clement. I know biber support \citetitle. But I want to print "title" using bibtex and natbib. Can we print "title" with bibtex?.

Comment: @user93268 That's another question.