# Author undefined for citation

Tags: citing

I have a question about an error message "(author?) [5]" rendered into my PDF. I'd very much like to render just the number in brackets. My bib file created with BibDesk looks like this:

```
@book{Martin_2002,
Author = {Martin, Robert Cecil},
Date-Added = {2016-04-03 19:49:12 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2016-04-03 19:49:46 +0000},
Publisher = {Prentice Hall Computer},
Title = {Agile Software Development. Principles, Patterns, and Practices},
Year = {2002}}
```

I'm citing using this configuration:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\setcitestyle{numbers,open={[},close={]}}
...
\citet{Martin_2002}
```

The log file has plenty of warnings regarding the author:

```
Package natbib Warning: Author undefined for citation`Martin_2002'
```

The bibliography renders just fine:

```
[19] R. C. Martin, Agile Software Development. Principles, Patterns, and Practices. Prentice Hall Computer, 2002.
```

I'm quite the tex noob. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What is the output? Make a citations section (`\makebibliography` or similar) and tell us what it does. Is there anthing missing?

Answer (score 1):

Using this bibstyle file answered my question:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

It was a duplicate of [Natbib In-Text Citation displays (author?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111790/natbib-in-text-citation-displays-author). Thanks for the help!