# naturemag bibliography style doesn't support citeyear and citeauthor

Tags: bibliographies, citing, bibliographystyle

It seems this bibliography style is not properly maintained or does not support certain commands to cite year and author separately. A warning is issued indicating there is no year available in the bibliography entry (although there is) and the text is replaced with **author?**.

Any idea how can I create a command to replicate the citeyear behaviour?

Example:

Warning I'm getting is:

> Package natbib Warning: Author undefined for citation `paperA'
> on page 6 on input line 339.

Then the output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think it would be relevant to add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to demonstrate the problem, to show which document class you are using, and to show what system you use to manage the bibliography.

Comment: Unrelated: Nature's referencing style is numeric: "References are each numbered, ordered sequentially as they appear in the text" (https://www.nature.com/nature/for-authors/formatting-guide). Author/year style would not be needed in that scheme. But it depends on what class and package(s) you are using, and whether or not it is the same Nature magazine under discussion.

Comment: What if I want to cite the publication year? or the author name?

Comment: The behaviour is similar to this issue
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111790/natbib-in-text-citation-displays-author

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using the `biblatex` style `nature` here, and moving away from 'classical' BibTeX if you can. (Note: I am the author of that style.)

Comment: I think that's the only solution I think. I'm looking for a two column template that would support such bibliography style, do you have any?